# Mount a directory of another server on boot automaticaly

Tags: linux, centos, mount, fstab, sshfs

I have two Centos 7 servers and I mounted a directory from the 2nd server on the 1st one by SSHFS.
And it works fine.

but when I reboot the 1st server I need to mount the directory manually.

What configuration does it need to mount the directory automatically after reboot?
I tried fstab but it must contain the password of 2nd server and I don't know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure ssh key based authentication here's [example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server), then configure automoint using fstab. Correct syntax is:

`user@host:/remote/folder /mount/point  fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,reconnect 0 0`

The important mount options here are noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev.

- noauto tells it not to mount at boot;
- x-systemd.automount tells device to mount only when accessed;
- _netdev tells it that it is a network device, not a block device (without it "No such device" errors might happen).